# How can I add unmanaged JARs in sbt-assembly to the final fat JAR?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

My project has dependencies on a JAR file that isn't in Ivy, how can I include it directly in the final JAR output by [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Figured out I just have to add them explicitly as unmanaged dependencies in `Build.scala`, they are not automatically pulled in from the `lib` folder.  Adding this line to settings worked:

`unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/vertica_jdk_5.jar")`

Comment: did you have to add anything to Build.scala in the end? I am trying to package some source code with an unmanaged jar located in "lib" folder at the base directory... but when I compare the size of the resulting jar, it is smaller than the unmanaged jar

Comment: what/where is Build.scala  in project ?

Answer (score 16):

For a single project setup, putting jars into `lib` should work. If you have multi-project setup the `lib` directory would be under each subproject like `app/lib`.

Comment: This bit of information saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: Absolutely works.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for those searching unmanaged dependencies: Updated documentation for `0.13.2` is here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html