# How to install scodec library in scala/sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, scodec

I have been asked by my developers to have scodec libraries installed on a linux server and I'm lost as I can't find any documentation that points about installing the scodec library!

Comment: You generally do not install Java / Scala libraries on the server.

Answer (score 4):

[scodec](https://github.com/scodec/) has 11 repositories in github. This is [scodec.org](http://scodec.org/), the official documentation. Seems like the [releases](http://scodec.org/releases/) page on the docs, is not very updated. So I am going to elaborate on the repositories based on github:

### scodec-bits

Provides persistent datatypes for working with bits and bytes.

Add the following into your `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scodec" %% "scodec-bits" % "1.1.23"
```

[Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scodec/scodec-bits) link. [Github](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-bits) link.

### scodec-stream

Scodec-stream is a library for streaming binary encoding and decoding. It is built atop scodec and fs2.

Add the following into your `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scodec" %% "scodec-stream" % "2.0.0"
```

[Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scodec/scodec-stream) link. [Github](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-stream) link.

### scodec-protocols

Provides models of common binary protocols using the scodec library.

Add the following into your `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scodec" %% "scodec-protocols" % "2.0.0"
```

[Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scodec/scodec-protocols) link. [Github](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-protocols) link.

### scodec

[Github](https://github.com/scodec/scodec) link. This package DO NOT publish to Maven central/Sonatype. Hence you cannot fetch it this way. You can try to download one of the [releases](https://github.com/scodec/scodec/releases) and read [How can I add unmanaged JARs in sbt-assembly to the final fat JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18749406/2359227)

### scodec-cats

Integration between scodec and cats.

Add the following into your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scodec" %% "scodec-cats" % "1.0.0"
```

[Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scodec/scodec-cats) link. [Github](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-cats) link.

### scodec-build

This repository contains an SBT plugin that is used by the SBT builds of the other scodec modules. It is not intended for direct use.

I will not elaborate about this one. If there is a need for that please comment and I'll add details.

### scodec.github.io

No releases yet. Skipping as well. [Github](https://github.com/scodec/scodec.github.io) link.

### scodec-website

Source for scodec.org website. Hence skipping.

### scodec-spire

Integration between scodec and spire. This package last publish was at 2016, and it was for Scala 2.11. But you can add it with:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scodec" %% "scodec-spire" % "0.4.0"
```

[Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scodec/scodec-spire) link. [Github](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-spire) link.

I skipped [scodec-scalaz](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-scalaz) and [scodec-akka](https://github.com/scodec/scodec-akka) which are archived.

I hope this will give you an idea where to start.

Comment: I did try your answer but am getting a syntax error!   " [error] Expected ';' "

Comment: @TomerShetah Thanks for the detailed answer. I will give it a try. However, i have a doubt, after doing this, will the library be available for all the users or just for me since i did the build?

Comment: @RajeshReddyB whoever has the needed code in its `build.sbt` will have it. Check it in your source control so everyone will have it.