# Add lib dir to IntelliJ for unmanaged sbt dependencies

Tags: scala, jar, intellij-idea, sbt

sbt allows manually copying in jars to `lib/` - it will find and use these unmanaged dependencies.  IntelliJ, though, can't seem to find anything I put it that dir.  How can I tell it to use them?

Comment: If you have the jars in the `lib` folder you need to add it to the class path in file -> project structure -> libraries

Comment: @EndeNeu is this true for sbt projects not in IntelliJ? The sbt documentation is really unclear about where the lib folder for jars should be in the sbt directory structure

Comment: @redeagle47 I don't think so but I'm also no 100% sure as I've never done such a thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to add these manually:

1. Menu File - Project structure
2. Left side: Select "Modules"
3. Right side: Select "Dependencies tab"
4. Click "+"
5. Choose "Jars or directories"

Comment: i was hoping that IntelliJ sbt plugin would automagically detect it...oh well, maybe in a future version of the plugin.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work in a multi-module sbt project  (Intellij 2017.3.4, sbt 1.1.1, Scala 2.12.4).  By trial and error, I came up with a  possible workaround, described in   https://stackoverflow.com/a/48814413/8439351

Answer (score 2):

After adding the jars to the lib directory , add this line in `build.sbt`

`exportJars := true`

Answer (score 1):

Create a lib directory directly under your project directory and place your jar (or symbolic link to jar) there. Note, if you're executing sbt from command prompt, you'll need to be in the project directory for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [How to add Jar libraries to an IntelliJ Idea SBT Scala project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796004/how-to-add-jar-libraries-to-an-intellij-idea-sbt-scala-project).

The better way to do it is to add your unmanaged dependencies to your build.sbt and refrain from leaving part of your dependency management to your IDE.

Refer to http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html for details on how to define your unmanagedBase and unmanagedJars tasks.